# How to iterate a map in SPL?

Tags: spl

I want to iterate a map but its giving *"unknown identifier referenced in the spl program"* on line 2.

```
logic state: { mutable map<uint32,rstring> ageNameMap ={}; 
               mutable MapIterator it;//2
       }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (unit32 in ageNameMap){

...
}
```

This resolved my problem.